# Is it “too much” if I ask to meet with my PI and ask her to sign my copy of her dissertation?

Tags: advisor, etiquette

I got into an internship with my PI this summer. She accepted me.  I’m so thrilled, I’m loving it, but today was the first day she actually came in, as she is usually at her other lab in NY. I mean, she glanced over at me and my mentor for like half a second because she was going by in a hurry and even with that I almost fainted.  When I meet her for real one on one I’m gonna die. I’m ready to go to heaven.

But seriously… This is my idol, my #1. I don’t even think she knows how much I value her and know her work by heart. If you asked me to write a summary of all her research I could give you at least 20 pages, probably more.

Anyways, as a professor do you think this is too much or over the top? What would you think if a student was like this about you? Is it too much if I ask her if I can meet her one on one or about autographing her dissertation?

Comment: Maybe I'm just getting old, but all the emoji in a question on a professional site seems a bit over the top to me.

Comment: To consolidate some further discussion about the emojis: the consensus seems to be that they are pertinent in this case, and so we will leave them.

Answer (score 5):

I've given signed copies of my thesis to my PhD adviser and to friends and colleagues who helped me with it as a token of gratitude. Signing books is also common. I see nothing wrong with you asking her to sign your copy.

As others have pointed out, you have to figure out a way to have a *professional relationship* with your adviser. Whatever her status in your (research) community, *to you* she is a professional contact with whom you have to productively interact. In your specific context, you aren't some screaming fan at a K-Pop concert, but you're the stage hand making sure that the microphone is working or the person at the back of the stage singing backing vocals -- a professional who is necessary to keep the show running. You've got to keep your cool to make sure it does.

Answer (score 4):

> What would you think if a student was like this about you?

Extremely uncomfortable. This is absolutely subjective; others may find this behavior flattering or appreciate the enthusiasm, but a non-negligible set of people will become cautious.

By and large, one expects a certain level of maturity and professionalism amongst research colleagues. Both those qualities imply moderation of emotions and appropriate expression. Bear in mind that gushing is communication; communication can make or break a researcher.

This is not only about academic mores and conduct; maturity is critical in research because work must be done dispassionately. Negative results must be accepted as readily as positive results, findings that reject your initial hypothesis must be clearly reported, and competition with research rivals must be above board, no matter the temptation. Each of these (and many more) can get difficult when one is emotionally driven. You must take care not to cultivate qualities that could impede your own research career.

As to the primary question; getting a dissertation copy autographed is no big deal under usual circumstances. Your adulation of this person makes the circumstances somewhat unusual, and the verbal/non-verbal cues you may give off could lead to uneasiness.

As others have said, your passion and enthusiasm are commendable. It's just that there is also a case for dispassion and stoicism in this domain.

Answer (score 3):

Wait to ask her until you've worked with her and know better how she might respond. Perhaps that's when your summer internship ends in a few months. In the meanwhile, don't faint at your first meeting. It's unprofessional.

Answer (score 0):

It never hurts to ask. I would not ask for a meeting for the sole purpose of getting an autograph, but it's perfectly reasonable to email a professor (especially one you're interning with) and ask whether they have time to meet with you and discuss research ideas. If at some point in the meeting you ask for an autograph, it's not too weird in my opinion (though it really is personal - some people might find it weird). I would suggest having the autograph bit at the end, so that it won't set the tone for the entire meeting.